# Can we append to a {% block %} rather than overwrite?

Tags: django, django-templates

In my core.html I have a block labeled javascript.  It would be great if I can append more lines to this block without overwriting everything in it.

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
{% block javascript %}
    {{ block.super }}
    ... more content ...
{% endblock %}
```

See: [Django documentation - Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Answer (score 13):

Using `block.super` works fine when extending a template but not as well when including one, ie:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} vs. {% include "partial.html" %}
```

Say you want to include a template in the middle of your page and you'd also like it to add some javascript in a block at the end of the page: calling `block.super` in the included template will crash.

Cf. Django issues [#7324](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7324), [#12008](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12008), [#13399](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13399) and the [related update to the documentation](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b729ef0bda5009389da7e3a5498dc1f6233761d6). Cf. [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-include) note:

> The include tag should be considered as an implementation of “render this subtemplate and include the HTML”, not as “parse this subtemplate and include its contents as if it were part of the parent”. This means that there is no shared state between included templates – each include is a completely independent rendering process.
>
> Blocks are evaluated before they are included. This means that a template that includes blocks from another will contain blocks that have already been evaluated and rendered - not blocks that can be overridden by, for example, an extending template.

In that case I'd recommend using [django-sekizai](https://django-sekizai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), wich allow you to do things like:

```
{% load sekizai_tags %}

                                ⎧  <p>Some content</p>
<p>Some content</p>             | {% addtoblock "js" %}
                                |   <script type="text/javascript">
{% include "partial.html" %} -> ⎨     alert("Hello django-sekizai");
                                |   </script>
<p>Some more content</p>        ⎩ {% endaddtoblock %}


{% render_block "js" %}
```

From [django-sekizai README](https://github.com/ojii/django-sekizai):

> The main reason I started this project was the lack of a good media (css/js) framework in django and the django-cms. Yes there is the Media class used in forms in django, but really that doesn't work that well. Usually the frontend guys want to decide on css and javascript files to be included and they don't want to have to edit Python files to change that neither did I want them to change my Python files. Therefor there was a need to allow you to edit contents of templates which are before or after the point where you are now. Also I wanted duplicates to be removed. As a result I wrote django-sekizai, which does exactly that. It's similar to blocks, just instead of inheriting them, you extend them.