# How to concatenate a content block in a Django template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we append to a {% block %} rather than overwrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724466/can-we-append-to-a-block-rather-than-overwrite)

Simply, I've got a Django app which relies upon a ton of jQuery. There are numerous issues with having multiple $(document).ready functions in a single page (e.g., click events firing multiple times). I believe that the way to go about this would be to concatenate a content block which displays in the footer, but I can't seem to find any examples of how to accomplish this.

How would the community suggest dynamically creating/extending the contents of a single $(document).ready function in a Django template?

**UPDATE**

The {{ block.super }}, as proposed in the first comment, works when called from a template, but I'm also using a variety of template tags which need to be able to add to the $(document).ready(). When called from within an inclusion tag, Django returns an AttributeError exception stating: 'BlockNode' object has no attribute 'context'.

Comment: This answer might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724466/can-we-append-to-a-block-rather-than-overwrite

Comment: @msc Excellent find. Voting to mark a duplicate, since the problem and solution are pretty much identical.

Comment: It's working! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks so much.
@cdhowie Please forgive my relative ignorance. I'd agree that the issue is essentially the same, but since this describes my issue inre jQuery in detail, is it properly a duplicate question?

Comment: @jonahs It may not be a precise duplicate in the details, but the question title considered alone makes it seem like one, and the question posed in the title does seem to be the primary one you are asking here.  I'm on the fence about it; other users can vote to close if they feel it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: The solution is only somewhat working for me, as it turns out. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, `block` tags inside of inclusion tag templates don't function the same way (they can't reference blocks in the template that called the tag).  I'm not sure that inclusion tags are your best option here if you need to inject data elsewhere in the document too.

Comment: I inherited a nightmare Django app (170k+ lines and counting). Unfortunately, I've got sometimes dozens of elements which need to be conditionally included and dynamically populated. I haven't yet found a better way of doing that than the use of inclusion tags. If I come up with something workable I'll be sure to update. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options, and the one that you would choose to go with depends on how complex your logic for choosing the code you need is, how interdependent the code blocks are on one another, and how they relate to the page markup.  You could simply store chunks of code as [inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags), and then invoke those tags in either your footer script section or your single `$(document).ready` section.  Or you could use something like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html).