# How do I add buttons to the navbar in pinax-project-account?

Tags: django, pinax

I'm using Pinax "account" starter project and it's great! Now I'm trying to figure out how to add buttons to the navbar at the top:

[image: Pinax starter project - current look]

When I dig into the source code, I find mysite/templates/site_base.html, which has the following code at the top:

```
{% extends "theme_bootstrap/base.html" %}
```

In that file "base.html", I found the code for navbar:

```
...
    <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}" id="{% block body_id %}{% endblock %}" {% block body_extra_attributes %}{% endblock %}>
        <div class="{% block wrapper_class %}{% endblock %}">

            {% block topbar_base %}
                <header>
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default {% block navbar_class %}navbar-fixed-top{% endblock %}">
                        <div class="container">
                        {% block topbar %}
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                    <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
                                </button>
                                {% block site_brand %}<a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url "home" %}">{{ SITE_NAME }}</a>{% endblock %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                                {% block nav %}
                                    {% comment %}
                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                            <li><a href="#tab_one">One</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#tab_two">Two</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    {% endcomment %}
                                {% endblock %}
                                {% block account_bar %}{% include "_account_bar.html" %}{% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </header>
            {% endblock %}
...
```

However, I was only able to access this file because I used the jump shortcut from the first site_base.html in PyCharm; I'm guessing "base.html" is bundled in a Django app. So, my question is: how do I change the navbar? A more specific question: How to add more buttons to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to find where `base.html` resides. I think PyCharm should show you the path to each opened file. Then,in the `base.html` file,  to add more buttons you simply remove the `comment` and `endcomment` template tags inside `nav` block and add more `li` items in the `ul`

```
{% block nav %}

   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#tab_one">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_two">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_three">Three</a></li> # added
       <li><a href="#tab_four">Four</a></li> # added
   </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**EDIT**

If, for any reasons, you don't want to edit the `base.html` file, then you can add in your `mysite/templates/site_base.html` file a `nav` block with the `ul` and the links you want. Basically you can add

```
{% block nav %}
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#tab_one">One</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_two">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="#tab_three">Three</a></li> # added
       <li><a href="#tab_four">Four</a></li> # added
   </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

inside the `site_base.html`, in the right place, and this will override the same block from `base.html`.

Comment: i don't think that would be stable or deployment-friendly; that script resides in a pre-built package/app

Comment: Thanks... I think I found a better option as I was hunting... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724466/can-we-append-to-a-block-rather-than-overwrite ... haven't tried it yet

Comment: so i needed to use a combination of both your answer and the one I linked for better customisability. Thanks!